# Writing shapefile metadata with geotools

Tags: shapefile, geotools

Using GeoTools, I'm able to write features to a shapefile by essentially passing a `SimpleFeatureCollection` to a `ShapefileDataStore`. The feature collection provides both a schema and features including their attribute values.

In addition to having the row-per-feature attribute table in the shapefile, I'd like to include file-level metadata - either structured fields or at least free-text title/description fields. Is there support for doing this in GeoTools? Or do I need to serialise my own `*.shp.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ,shp,xml file is a later ESRI specific addition to the 'standard' and is not documented anywhere so is not supported by GeoTools (or any one else).

The package [`org.geotools.data.shapefile.xml`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/shapefile/shp/xml) has a [`ShpXmlFileReader`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/shapefile/shp/xml/ShpXmlFileReader.java), but no `ShpXmlFileWriter` yet.

If you do develop some code to serialize metadata then feel free to offer it back to the GeoTools team.